# How to listen for final reports with MORYX

Tags: c#, moryx

I am handling production orders with [MORYX](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Framework). When an order gets reported, I want to send related data to a 3rd party service.

For **partial** reports I use the *OrderManagements* `OperationPartialReport` event:

```cs
_orderManagement.OperationPartialReport += OnOperationPartialReport;
```

For **final** reports, though, I can't find an equivalent that seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MORYX a final report completes the operation and therefor you receive the final report in the [`OperationCompleted`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Factory/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Orders/Facade/IOrderManagement.cs#L108) event.

You can use the same listener as your partial report, as they have the same signature.

```cs
_orderManagement.OperationPartialReport += OnOperationReport;
_orderManagement.OperationCompleted += OnOperationReport;
```